# how to make sure a program or shared library is compiled with -g, in linux

Tags: linux, debugging, gcc

I want to make sure my execute program is debug-able, what command can get the infomation.

Comment: Erm, well, you compile it with `-g` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use objdump with the --debugging and --debugging-tags options

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of using `file` to get information on executables and shared libraries.

The one key you are looking for is `stripped` in the description. If it is stripped it definitely does not have your debug symbols. Sadly, I am thinking a binary can still have no debug info but not be stripped.

$ file /usr/bin/file
/usr/bin/file: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped